# Login fallido. Send_keys() no envía la frase completa en python

Tags: python, login, selenium

Buenos días

Estoy intentando hacer loggin a una página web con selenium y chromedirver. Tengo todos los elementos localizados y lo único que me falla es que al enviar la contraseña, se está mandadno una sub cadena de caracteres de longitud aleatoria.

Os dejo el código a ver si conseguís averiguar qué falla.

**Mi código**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Visente\Desktop\Pablito Python\chromedriver.exe")  

urlbet='https://www.bet365.es/?&cb=103265469#/HO/'

browser.get(urlbet)

sport=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dv1"]/a')))

sport.click()

user=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input')))

passw=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input[1]')
user.send_keys('username')
passw.send_keys('my_password')

submit=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button')
submit.click()
```

Para quien no sea de España y no pueda probar. La página es de bet365. Tanto el campo usuario como el de contraseña tienen escrito antes de hacer nada "usuario" y "contraseña". En usuario se sobre escribe sin problema.

En contraseña si utilizo get_attribute('value') para ver qué se ha escrito viene precedido de Cotnraseña.

Después de escribir el primer caracter, el x_path cambia a input[2] al final del mismo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] puppet. He editado mi respuesta original porque no me había percatado de que "había truco oculto" :). He probado el código y tanto usuario como contraseña son ingresados en sus respectivos inputs correctamente. No he probado el login al carecer de cuenta pero no debe haber problemas, en cualquier caso comenta si tienes alguno. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el verdadero `input` (de tipo `password`) está oculto y solo es visible cuando el foco se encuentra en el `input` de tipo `text` donde aparece el texto "Contraseña". Por eso te cambia el x_path al ingresar el primer carácter.

Una posible solución pasa por seleccionar el `input` de tipo `text`, hacer click en él, seleccionar el segundo y entonces usar `send_keys` sobre este:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Visente\Desktop\Pablito Python\chromedriver.exe")  

urlbet='https://www.bet365.es/?&cb=103265469#/HO/'

browser.get(urlbet)

sport=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dv1"]/a')))

sport.click()

user=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input')))

passw=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".hm-Login_PasswordWrapper > input:nth-child(1)")

user.clear()
user.send_keys('username')
passw.click()

passw = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.hm-Login_InputField:nth-child(2)")))

passw.clear()
passw.send_keys('my_password')

submit=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button')
submit.click()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora si funciona. Por curiosidad, por qué has cambiado a selectores Css? Te lo pregunto porque a mi también se me ocurrió el buscar con la nueva ruta tras hacer click, pero lo hice con x_path y me seguía dando error. Entonces como no domino mucho los selectores, no se si es por las ventajas de css sobre x_path, o simplemente que por el camino algo escribí mal.

Comment: @puppet es más una costumbre, aunque usar x_path es confiable, las xpath generadas de forma dinámica dependen de la estructura del DOM., un cambio mínimo en esta estructura puede ocasionar la perdida de funcionalidad del spider/scraper. No obstante creo que deberías poder hacerlo, ahora no puedo probar nada porque estoy desde móvil. dado que eres nuevo por aquí te comento que puedes aceptar aquellas respuestas que consideres que solucionan tu pregunta, para saber como funciona puedes mirarte:[¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089?) . Saludos